# How we can access the result variables inside OnclickListener into another function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-developer-api

**I have same variables which got after onClickLisener Activity and not i want to access that variable in another function.**

`
class EMIPayment : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var amountEt: EditText
var noteEt: String = "EMI"
var nameEt: String = "Swayambhu"
var upiIdEt: String = "XXXXXXXXX@ibl"
lateinit var send: Button

```
internal val UPI_PAYMENT = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emipayment)

    title = "EMI Payment"
    supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(
        ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"))
    )
    try {
        val calculateEMI = findViewById<Button>(R.id.calculateEMI)
        //val result2= Math.round(result*10.0)/10.0
        //val result2= Math.round(result*10.0)/10.0
        calculateEMI.setOnClickListener {
            val emiView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.EMIView)
            val pe = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.loanAmount)
            val pe2 = pe.text.toString()+"000"
            val pe3 = pe2.toDouble()
            val ne = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.tenure)
            val p = pe3
            val n = ne.text.toString().toDouble()
            val r = 0.01717
            val result = (p * r * (1 + r).pow(n)) / ((1 + r).pow(n) - 1)
            val result2 = String.format("%.2f",result).toDouble() **Want to access this value**
            val fin = result2 * 1
           emiView.text = fin.toString()
        }

    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "An Error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    initializeViews()
    
    send.setOnClickListener {
        //Getting the values from the EditTexts
        val amount = amountEt.text.toString()
        val note = noteEt
        val name = nameEt
        val upiId = upiIdEt
        payUsingUpi(amount, upiId, name, note)
    }
}
internal fun initializeViews() {

    send = findViewById(R.id.payEMI)
    amountEt = findViewById(R.id.EMIView) **At Here**
    //noteEt = findViewById(R.id.note)
    //nameEt = findViewById(R.id.name)
    //upiIdEt = findViewById(R.id.upi_id)
}

fun payUsingUpi(amount: String, upiId: String, name: String, note: String) {

    val uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", upiId)
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", name)
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", note)
        .appendQueryParameter("am", amount)
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .build()


    val upiPayIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    upiPayIntent.data = uri

    // will always show a dialog to user to choose an app
    val chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with")

    // check if intent resolves
    if (null != chooser.resolveActivity(packageManager)) {
        startActivityForResult(chooser, UPI_PAYMENT)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this@EMIPayment, "No UPI app found, please install one to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    when (requestCode) {
        UPI_PAYMENT -> if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode || resultCode == 11) {
            if (data != null) {
                val trxt = data.getStringExtra("response")
                Log.d("UPI", "onActivityResult: $trxt")
                val dataList = ArrayList<String>()
                dataList.add(trxt.toString())
                upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList)
            } else {
                Log.d("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + "Return data is null")
                val dataList = ArrayList<String>()
                dataList.add("nothing")
                upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList)
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + "Return data is null") //when user simply back without payment
            val dataList = ArrayList<String>()
            dataList.add("nothing")
            upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList)
        }
    }
}

private fun upiPaymentDataOperation(data: ArrayList<String>) {
    if (isConnectionAvailable(this@EMIPayment)) {
        var str: String? = data[0]
        Log.d("UPIPAY", "upiPaymentDataOperation: " + str!!)
        var paymentCancel = ""
        if (str == null) str = "discard"
        var status = ""
        var approvalRefNo = ""
        val response = str.split("&".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
        for (i in response.indices) {
            val equalStr = response[i].split("=".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            if (equalStr.size >= 2) {
                if (equalStr[0].toLowerCase() == "Status".toLowerCase()) {
                    status = equalStr[1].toLowerCase()
                } else if (equalStr[0].toLowerCase() == "ApprovalRefNo".toLowerCase() || equalStr[0].toLowerCase() == "txnRef".toLowerCase()) {
                    approvalRefNo = equalStr[1]
                }
            } else {
                paymentCancel = "Payment cancelled by user."
            }
        }

        if (status == "success") {
            //Code to handle successful transaction here.
            Toast.makeText(this@EMIPayment, "Transaction successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.d("UPI", "responseStr: $approvalRefNo")
        } else if ("Payment cancelled by user." == paymentCancel) {
            Toast.makeText(this@EMIPayment, "Payment cancelled by user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this@EMIPayment, "Transaction failed.Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this@EMIPayment, "Internet connection is not available. Please check and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

companion object {

    fun isConnectionAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            val netInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected
                && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
                && netInfo.isAvailable) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

}`

**I have got the Eception**
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.sw001, PID: 18881 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sw001/com.example.sw001.EMIPayment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3687) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3844) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:110) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2262) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7941) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1009) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText **at com.example.sw001.EMIPayment.initializeViews$app_debug(EMIPayment.kt:75)** **at com.example.sw001.EMIPayment.onCreate(EMIPayment.kt:61)** at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8059) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8039) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1335) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3844)  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:110)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2262)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7941)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1009)`

Comment: In your layout resource, `R.id.EMIView` points to a `TextView`, not an `EditText`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I've tried it...Actually, it's a text view, and I want to show the EMI amount on the screen. can you please suggest another option ??

Comment: "Actually, it's a text view, and I want to show the EMI amount on the screen" -- then change your declaration of `amountEt` to be a `TextView`, not an `EditText`. Or, [switch to view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and remove the `findViewById()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the solution yet. Look for how you are declaring the view `amountEt` it seems you are doing it like `val amountEt: EditText` when it is a `TextView` in xml. You cant cast a TextView to an EditText.
That is what `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText **at com.example.sw001.EMIPayment.initializeViews()`  says. Either change it to `EditText` tag in xml if you want to use Text input field. Or do it with `lateinit var amountEt: TextView` in your code if its a TextView you want.